# Error gotten in integising strings in .split() list

Tags: python, try-catch, nose

Im starting to learn python can someone pls tell me how to OK this nosetest:

```
from nose.tools import *

    from lexicon.lexicon import lexicon
    def test_directions():
        assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
        result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
        assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                              ('direction', 'south'),
                              ('direction', 'east')])
    def test_numbers():
        assert_equal(lexicon.scan("1234"), [('number', 1234)])
        result = lexicon.scan("3 91234")
        assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                              ('number', 91234)])
```

I used the folowing code to pass the first test but couldnt pass `test_numbers()`.

```
directions = ['north','south','east','east','down','up','left','right','back','front']
class lexicon:
    @staticmethod
    def scan(d):
        list1 = [('direction', x) for x in d.split() if x in directions]
        try:
            list2 = [('number',int(x)) for x in d.split() if int(x) in xrange(999999)]
        except ValueError:
            return None   
        return list1 + list2
```

I am thinking I am misusing the use of `try` .Please help me out

Comment: Is this your actual exact indentation? Your `return` statement is outside of your function.

Comment: @kevin No. I didn't run it like this.it was a mistake while I was typing it in

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
try:
    x = something_that_raises_an_error()
except:
    return y
```

does not set `x = y`. It simply performs the statement inside the `except` block, so it returns `y`.

When you run `scan("north")` and it goes into the `except ValueError:` block it returns `None`. That means the function ends right there and `scan("north") is None`. Replace `return None` with either `list2 = []` or `return list1`.

(also, if somehow your code set `list2 = None` that wouldn't work either because `list1 + None` will fail - you can't add a list to a non-list and `None` is not a list)

But this will only get you so far because now when you pass a mixture of words and numbers you won't get any of the numbers. You need to use the `try` block inside a loop so that it can do the right thing for each value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution to the problem

```
directions =['north','south','east','east','down','up','left','right','back','front']
numbers = xrange(999999999)
class lexicon:
    @staticmethod
    def scan(d):
        list2=d.split()
        list1=[]
        list3=[]
        try:
            for x in d.split(): 

                if int(x) in xrange(999999999):
                    a = x

                    list1.append(a)
                    list2.remove(a)
                else:
                    print "yes"
        except:
            list99=[]
        for x in d.split():
            if x in directions:
                z2 = ("direction" , x)
                list3.append(z2)
            elif x in list1:
                z2 = ("number" , int(x))
                list3.append(z2)
            elif x in list2:
                z2 = ("error" , x)
                list3.append(z2)
        return list3
```

With this it runs perfect